# SQL Parsing XML for a specific node and its tags

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssms, nodes

I am using the following to get a specific XML:

```
DECLARE @queryID INT = 1 

/* get xml with queryID */
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = (SELECT TOP 1 myPlan FROM myTable 
                WHERE stmtID in (@queryID))
```

the XML it returns looks something like this:

```
<xmlPlan>
<myOp id='0' usage='0.75'>
    ....
    <myOp id='2' usage='0.45'>
        ...
    </myOp>
    <myOp id ='3' usage='0.30'>
        ...
    </myOp>
</myOp>
<myOp id='1' usage='0.35'>
    ...
</myOp>
```

I need to parse this XML for myOp nodes and see if their usage tag is greater than .50. These should always be leaf nodes but their nested levels can change.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (I added some nodes around an within your nodes):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<xmlPlan>
<myOp id="0" usage="0.75">
    <OuterNode SomeAttr="outer1">
    <myOp id="2" usage="0.45">
        <someInnerNode SomeAttr="inner1"/>
    </myOp>
    <myOp id ="3" usage="0.30">
        <anotherInnerNode SomeAttr="inner2"/>
    </myOp>
    </OuterNode>
</myOp>
<myOp id="1" usage="0.35">
    <InnerNode SomeAttr="inner3" />
</myOp>
</xmlPlan>';
```

--The query

```sql
SELECT A.n.value('local-name(..)','nvarchar(max)') AS ParentName
      ,A.n.value('../@SomeAttr','nvarchar(max)') AS ParentAttr
      ,A.n.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,A.n.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS LocalID
      ,A.n.value('@usage','nvarchar(max)') AS LocalType
FROM @xml.nodes('/xmlPlan//myOp[@usage > 0.4]') A(n);
```

The query will use the *deep search (`//`)* below `/xmlPlan` to find **any `<myOp>`** wherever it is placed. The predicate `[@usage > 0.4]` will pick just those, where the attribute `usage` exceeds 0.4 (two rows in this case).

The rest is some meta information you might need - or not...